# Trying to write a JSON to a file using JSON Spirit in C++

Tags: c++, json, json-spirit

I am trying to write to a JSON to a file using [JSON Spirit](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20027/JSON-Spirit-A-C-JSON-Parser-Generator-Implemented).

I am using the code similar to the examples given on the website to do this as follows:

```
json_spirit::Object emotion_json;
emotion_obj.push_back(json_spirit::Pair("Dominant emotion", "Joy"));

ofstream os("emotion_json.json");
json_spirit::write(emotion_obj, os);
os.close();
```

I keep getting the error:

```
undefined reference to 'json_spirit::write(json_spirit::Value_impl<json_spirit::Config_vector<std::string> > const&, std::ostream&, int, unsigned int)'
```

I tried different variations witin JSON Spirit to output the JSON to a file, but none of them seem to be working for me despite having the headers:

```
#include <json_spirit.h>
#include <json_spirit_writer_template.h>
#include <json_spirit_writer.h>
```

Any idea what might be going on? Also, if there is a better, light-weight library to create JSON structures in C++, I am all ears. Thanks!

Comment: In what IDE did you compile it?

Comment: I compiled it from the command line. I have a mac and the SDK I need to use is written for linux. So I am writing in eclipse on my mac then pushing/pulling from git onto a virtual machine.

Comment: Undefined reference message is produced by linker. It means there is declaration that isn't supplemented by implementation, for example if you added library headers but forgot to add library itself to linker parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on the linking option:

```
-ljson_spirit
```

If compiler cannot find `json_spirit`, use

```
-L /path/to/the/parent/folder/of/libjson_spirit.a
```

before `json_spirit` and after the name of `.cpp` file.

If you cannot find any `libjson_spirit.a`, you should build the library.

Go to the folder `json_spirit` in the source code where you see file `CMakeLists.txt`.

In the command line type:

```
cmake .
make
```

Then `libjson_spirit.a` will be created.

Comment: I throw that command into my compile statement, but then it says it can't find `-ljson_spirit`.

Comment: @agaidis, is it in `/usr/local/lib` any the equivalent for Mac?

Comment: I don't have any file with the `.a` extension. Didn't come in the source code. When I do `-L /path/to/json_spirit_stuff` the same error appears.

Comment: I really appreciate the effort you are putting into this. Thank you. I got the file `libjson_spirit.a` after following your most recent update. However, after linking the file when I compile, I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: @agaidis, did you use `-L json_spirit -ljson_spirit` for linker option? if not, what did you use exactly?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use both. It says cannot find `-ljson_spirit` flag.

Comment: @agaidis, have you done `make install` after `make`?

Comment: I did `cmake .` then `make` then when I try `make install` it says `No rule to make target 'install'`

Comment: Eclipse has special place to put library references under Project Properties - C++ build - settings - c++ linker - libraries. You can add path to your .a there, if it doesn't allow installation.

Comment: @ZuOverture I am not building on Eclipse unfortunately.

Comment: I tested the code. It compiles and links fine for me using: `g++ -I./json_spirit_v4.08/json_spirit/ main.cpp -L ./json_spirit_v4.08/json_spirit/ -ljson_spirit`

Comment: That worked!! I arranged the statements so they were in the same order as you. Oh man, thank you so much :)

Comment: @agaidis all linker options must be after your `.cpp` file.